# Starting mongo docker with docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

My docker container is running through docker-compose.  The init script appears to be creating the user I want to login with because of this log line:

```
mongo    | Successfully added user: { "user" : "newUser", "roles" : [ "readWrite" ] }
mongo    | bye
mongo    | Error saving history file: FileOpenFailed Unable to open() file /home/mongodb/.dbshell: No such file or directory
mongo    | {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-29T13:45:03.397+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:60066","connectionId":3,"connectionCount":0}}
```

However since I'm seeing the "unable to open file /home/mongodb/.dbshell", it appears I cannot write to my data directory. Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Here's the docker-compose for mongo:

```
mongo:
  image: mongo:4.4.3
  container_name: mongo
  restart: unless-stopped
  environment:
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root1
    MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: admin
  command: mongod --port 27017
  ports:
    - '27017:27017'
  volumes:
    - ./data/mongodb:/data/db
    - ./configs/mongodb/mongo-init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.sh:ro
```

This is my mongo-init.sh file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
mongo -- "admin" <<EOF
    var rootUser = 'root';
    var rootPassword = 'root1';
    var admin = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
    admin.auth(rootUser, rootPassword);

    var user = 'newUser';
    var passwd = 'newUserPass';
    db.createUser({user: user, pwd: passwd, roles: ["readWrite"]});
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  There were 2 places I was wrong in my scripts. The MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE should not have been admin in my docker-compose- it should have been the database I was trying to create.  The mongo-init.sh file should also have been like so instead:

```
mongo -- "newUserDB" <<EOF
    var admin = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
    admin.auth('root', 'root1');
    db.createUser({user: 'newUser', pwd: 'newUserPass', roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: "newUserDB" }]});
EOF
```

I noticed my user was getting created in the wrong database.  The error above was throwing me off.  That and the owner of the local volume was systemd-coredump, which is entirely ok because that's just a mapping of user ids that Mongo uses in the container.  Nothing to do with an actual core dump.  Fewf!